# What does Stack Overflow use to keep track of edits?

Tags: discussion, javascript, jquery

I am wondering how Stack Overflow keeps track of edits.
Does anyone know how it is done? I am talking about the characters added, etc.

I think Stack Overflow uses this Javascript diff algorithm:

> http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/

Comment: That plugin does not track diffs. That plugin displays diffs. This is a bit different from tracking diffs.

Comment: @Chichiray but couldn't it just then be the ejohn.org script used to compare files differentiated by some kind of naming scheme. Would think a git/svn implementation would be too much, don't you?